# Performance lack on delegate creation

Tags: c#, performance, linq, lambda

I have an app with repository pattern. It allows me to manipulate objects via LINQ, objects are stored in memory, so I can access them very fast. Here a sample code:

```
private Measurement ParseExact(AgentParameter agentParameter)
{
    ControlledElement ce;
    using (var repositoryBase = Datastore.GetRepository<ControlledElement>())
    {
        var mvId = Convert.ToInt32(agentParameter.ControlledParameterId);
        var sId = Convert.ToInt32(agentParameter.FacilityId);
        ce =
            repositoryBase.Query(
                t => t.FirstOrDefault(elem => elem.Sensor.Id == sId && elem.MeasuringValue.Id == mvId));
    }
}
```

When I profiled my code with dotTrace I found that on high load I get a performance lack on creating delegate `elem => elem.Sensor.Id == sId && elem.MeasuringValue.Id == mvId`. My Query method looks like:
`public TOut Query<TOut>(Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, TOut> specification)` which means, that I really pass a `Func<>` object every time I use it. So, the question is, how can I optimize this?

**EDIT** proof of lack on creation and compilation
[image]

Comment: If you've got an `IQueryable<T>`, shouldn't you be using an `Expression<Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, TOut>>` anyway? If you're really using a `Func<>`, that means all the data is being fetched locally and *then* filtered...

Comment: @JonSkeet i have `IQueryable` as a Generalization (query can be executed on db or in my cache provider). In this and exactly this case i wotk with my self-written cache, so i don't know, how to implement `Expression` in it... I haven't used them yet and don't know, what they are. Is it what i need?

Comment: Are you seeing poor performance on delegate *creation* or the *execution* of the delegated function?

Comment: @recursive creation and compilation. Added image to proof my words

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can eliminate the compilation step by explicitly tracking the state in an object, rather than using a closure.

```
private Measurement ParseExact(AgentParameter agentParameter)
{
    ControlledElement ce;
    using (var repositoryBase = Datastore.GetRepository<ControlledElement>())
    {
        var mvId = Convert.ToInt32(agentParameter.ControlledParameterId);
        var sId = Convert.ToInt32(agentParameter.FacilityId);
        var query = new ParseExactQuery(mvId, sId);
        ce = repositoryBase.Query(t => t.FirstOrDefault(query.Query));
    }
}

private class ParseExactQuery {
    private int mvId;
    private int sId;

    public ParseExactQuery (int mvId, int sId) {
        this.mvId = mvId;
        this.sId = sId;
    }

    public bool Query(ControlledElement elem) {
        return elem.Sensor.Id == sId && elem.MeasuringValue.Id == mvId;
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks a lot like display class created for lambda, won't this take nearly same time for object creation/garbage collection?

Comment: Wow! This gave me a real boost. I still have some expenses on GC, but code works much better. Thank you much! Anyway, it there any "correct" way to deal with such expressions (where lambda is created only to closure some variables?). I create such lambdas nearly 10000 times a second and guess it's not good implementation

Comment: I will admit I don't completely understand why this is so much better.  My guess is that your original implementation was re-creating the closure for every `ControlledElement`, whereas this change only creates it once per invocation of `ParseExact`.  I don't have a solid resource to back that up though.